# How to train an existing multilayer perceptron in weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, command-line, neural-network, weka

I want to know if there is a way of training an existing weka multilayer perceptron.

What I mean by this is that I have trained a model for 500 epochs and now I want to train it for another 100 to see if that improves its performance, potentially also changing the learning rate and/or momentum. Is this possible? If so how would you go about it, ideally through command line but if it requires java code that is also ok.

This is the original command:

java -cp weka.jar weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -t /Users/XX/Desktop/YY/Output/TenMoves.arff -d /Users/XX/Desktop/YY/Output/Models/model_80.model -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 80 > /Users/XX/Desktop/YY/Output/Results/Run_80.txt

And I have tried running it with the -l input file before -d but this did not work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just train two models using 500 and 600 epochs respectively and compare them?

Comment: The main barrier to this is simply how long that will take to do, what I really want to be able to do is load the weights of the trained model in rather than the defaults and then train for a further 100 epochs. (Takes about 5 days with my current setup to train a network for 500 epochs)

Comment: My first thought was to check whether this can be done in [MOA](https://moa.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) but I can't see MLP in the list of available models. I would try asking this one on the [Weka mailing list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist)

Comment: I tried the mailing list and got a fairly useful response, thank you!